# Libcurl - CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION - what is it for?

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

Tell me please, i just can't figure out what the CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION parameter is used for.

Yes, of course I read the entire description about CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION:

[CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION.html)

[timer_callback](https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/drive/multi-socket)

[hiperfifo](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/hiperfifo.html)

And I still don't understand what he does and why he is wanted.
For example:

> Certain features, such as timeouts and retries, require you to call
> libcurl even when there is no activity on the file descriptors.
>
> Your callback function timer_callback **should** install a non-repeating
> timer with an expire time of timeout_ms milliseconds. When that timer
> fires, call either **curl_multi_socket_action** or curl_multi_perform,
> depending on which interface you use.

I don't understand why I should call **curl_multi_socket_action()** from the **CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION** callback and not from the event callback?

Comment: You should not call curl_multi_socket_action() from CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION. You should set a timer and exit from CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION immediately. You should call curl_multi_socket_action() from a timer handler. *When that timer fires, call either curl_multi_socket_action or ...*

Comment: @S.M., Yes, I meant it, I just did not correctly formulate the phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for curl to take action when requests were not answered in time. You need to call curl back periodically so it does its own internal housekeeping.

Imagine you made a request to curl and curl took action on it but could not connect at that time. Curl cannot hang the process waiting for the connect so it returns the control to you and relies on you returning the control back to curl for checking if it can connect periodically.

Comment: that is, the timer callback function must be called periodically for such a check? Does this decrease performance?

Comment: Well "performance" is a very broad word. At that point curl is basically dead doing nothing, waiting so it's sort of a moot point talking about performance. If at all, you should be calling very frequently so curl can take action at the earliest possible.

Comment: But also: calling back prematurely before the timer expires or any socket has activity is a waste of CPU so even if works, it is inefficient.

Comment: @DanielStenberg It depends on how you define "efficient". I'm inclined to favor wasting CPU cycles for lower latency, to the point I turn off even C-states on my servers and spin everything at 100% cpu. Someone else would favor power consumption over responsivity. That is the point of my comment.

Comment: @Jellyboy, please tell me what you mean by - "could not connect at THAT time" In which - "THAT" ?

Comment: @Optimus1  It is a hypothetical situation. https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-TCP-connection-timeout

Comment: @Jellyboy,
all the same I can not understand in any way why the timer is needed then ?? Why interrupt the process with a timer? If an event has occurred and the OS says that there is data to read on this socket, then I must call curl_multi_socket_action (), if the OS says that there is data to write, I must call curl_multi_socket_action () again. I don't understand what the timer is for! :(

Comment: I previously implemented a small simple nttp 1.1 client based on a Windows socket and IO Completion ports - and I didn't have any timers! I ran the completion port handler in a separate thread and added tasks to the queue to send messages. The message handler reported the occurrence of a read or write event - and I did read or write and NO timer. CRAP! I don’t understand why the hell does libcurl need these timers.

Comment: @Optimus1 it's the opposite. It's when you DON'T get any event from the OS but some action needs to be taken. For example, a connect() will send a SYN packet but if the internet or the host is dropping connection attempts instead of rejecting, you will be left without any sort of answer. https://serverfault.com/questions/157375/reject-vs-drop-when-using-iptables

Comment: @Jellyboy, "you will be left without any sort of answer." - it shouldn't be that way, the OS will return an error.

Comment: It will not. In the worst case the connect() call will be there waiting for minutes or hours or forever unless curl sets a mechanism to timeout and recover.

Comment: @Jellyboy calling it **prematurely** is *wasting* CPU without any benefit though. That's why there's a timeout in the first place... (after all, I'm the author of this)

Comment: @DanielStenberg think about the case that curl timed out and just returned when the SYN-ACK packet comes back and then you wait another 100ms to finish with connect(). That's 100ms wasted. This discussion is worthless without requirements. If your requirement is latency, I'd actually spam-poll 100% cpu for the minimum response time. If your top requirement is cpu usage, then I'd sleep for long periods before rechecking.

Comment: @Jellyboy adding another call in that case won't do anything since libcurl will wait for its internal timeout before consider that an error so a user should then rather set a proper timeout value. Busy-looping will not make anything better. This is my last word on this here. I'm out.

Comment: I don’t really think you understand the context here